# How to create a peppermint candy swirl material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

What I want:

[image: img]

What I achieved so far:

[image: img]

The tutorial I'm following:

https://youtu.be/dDXw28BHkv4?t=286

Where I'm stuck:

Adding the **tangent** node doesn't result in the spiral effect as shown in the Tutorial here

[image: img]

What I'd expect:

Adding the **tangent** node results in spiral effect

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can combine a radial effect and a wave effect:

[image]

The disk is Z up, its radius is along X and Y.

The generated coordinates are centered to -0.5 to 0.5.

The wave is to have a sinus going along the radius, from the center to the edge.

The radial effect is to have a cosinus depending on the angle around the disk.

[image]

[image]